# Blockhound Gradle: 'You need to add '-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods' JVM flag.'

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, blockhound

I am trying to run Blockhound in my Spring Boot app during testing. Unfortunately gradle does not pick up the required `-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods` flag. I tried it using IntelliJ's VMoptions in Run Configurations as well as in gradle.properties `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods`. The error persists though.

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?

Gradle:

```
tasks.withType(Test).all {
        if (JavaVersion.current().isCompatibleWith​(JavaVersion.VERSION_15)) {
            jvmArgs += [
                    "-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods"
            ]
        }
    }
```

maven:

```
<plugins>
 ...
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.22.2</version>
             <configuration>
                 <argLine>-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods</argLine>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
 ...
 </plugins>
```

or JAVA_OPTS?
on mac/linux:

`export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods"`

or Windows

`set JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods"`

reference: https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/issues/33

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, unforunately I get this error now
`Unrecognized VM option 'AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: `java -version` gives me openjdk version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19

Comment: Is that the same version you get if you run `gradlew --version`?